# What Functional Language suits best for a Database Application?

Tags: functional-programming

I want to develop an application to connect to a PostgreSQL Database, I want to do it in a Functional Language, but I'm not sure what could be the best, I wanted to do it in Erlang, but it doesn't have a good and reliable driver, what language would you choose or use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either Haskell or one of the Java / .Net FP languages (Scala, Clojure, F#) would be the way I go. In the case of JVM / .Net, you get the JDBC/ADO.Net advantage. I do find the Haskell package to be usable though.

HDBC, if you are interested: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HDBC

edit: link to HDBC added.

Answer (score 1):

Any functional language that provide an interface to the PostgreSQL C API or to ODBC will do. If it has an ODBC wrapper, you can use it on both Windows and Linux (through UnixODBC). BTW, Clojure seems will be a good choice as it has better interoperability with existing Java classes and Java already have a mature database API.